# Spring Boot deployed in external tomcat gives 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I am following [this tutorial](https://codezup.com/deploy-spring-boot-war-to-external-tomcat/)  to deploy the Spring boot application to external tomcat. My java version is 1.8 and the tomcat server version is 8.5.  I have deployed my Spring boot application in tomcat but in tomcat-manager app, I can see that my application has not started and I am getting HTTP Status 404 – Not Found page.
Screenshot is giving below:
[image]
[image]
When I have tried to start my Spring boot application, I am getting the following error:

```
FAIL - Application at context path [/e-swift-api] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/e-swift-api]]]
```

What should I do?

Update:
WHen I am checking catalina.log, I am getting following error:

```
29-Jun-2022 16:53:14.931 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-5] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/e-swift-api]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1016)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1903)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jdbcConverter' parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5221)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
        ... 32 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        ... 46 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:330)
        at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$DefaultDialectProvider.getDialect(DialectResolver.java:107)
        at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver.lambda$getDialect$0(DialectResolver.java:77)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver.getDialect(DialectResolver.java:79)
        at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.AbstractJdbcConfiguration.jdbcDialect(AbstractJdbcConfiguration.java:144)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        ... 47 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
        ... 66 more
    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:523)
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:521)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:660)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:286)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518)
        ... 79 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection timed out: connect, socket connect lapse 21047 ms. /192.183.155.127 1521 30000 1 true
        at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:209)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:161)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:470)
        ... 84 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.<init>(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:81)
        at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:169)
        ... 86 more
```

Comment: Is that the entire stack trace? Are there no other errors that are causing the one you posted?

Comment: I have updated my post and  included the catalina.log

Comment: The actual problem is `IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`. Check your database configuration and how you're trying to connect. Your program is not able to connect to your database for some reason, and the details you have provided are insufficient to determine that reason.